# Why node.js always says I'm connected to my MongoDB even if the "URI" is fake or wrong?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, connection

I'm testing mongoDB connection in node.js with mongoose. I follow the official guide of mongoose and when I try to connect like they said, mongoose always says I'm connected even if the URI given is fake or wrong. Is my connection trying correct ?

I want to connect my app to a database called 'technicaltest'.

My code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/technicaltest', {useNewUrlParser: true});

db.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Connected to mongoDB !');
});

db.on('disconnected', () => {
    console.log('Disconnected to mongoDB !');
});
```

The console ouput:

```
> set PORT=3001 && node bin/www

Connected to mongoDB !
```

Same output for this code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/someWeirdyThingsHere', {useNewUrlParser: true});

db.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Connected to mongoDB !');
});

db.on('disconnected', () => {
    console.log('Disconnected to mongoDB !');
});
```

I think if mongoose cannot connect to the right database in mongoDB nothing will be prompted in the console...
But here...
The 'connected' event is call anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to add the port(27017) to your mongodb connection.
It should be

```
const db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/technicaltest', {useNewUrlParser: true});
```